# Runge-Kutta 3 on simple ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

It has been a very long time since I have worked with differential equations.

I have $y' = -y^2$ and $y(0) = 1$ and I want to solve this with RK$3$. I know the iterative formula for RK$3$, but I am not sure how to get this going with this 'odd' form of $y' = -y^2$. I'm used to getting something as $f(t_n,x_n)$.

$$ x_{n+1} = x_{n} + h \left( \frac{1}{6}k_1 + \frac{2}{3}k_2 + \frac{1}{6}k_3 \right) $$

How do I get this going?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to compute $k_{1}, k_{2}, k_{3}$?

Comment: @Mattos I know their formulas, but I am not sure how to get them going with the given information.

Comment: $k_{1} = f(t_{n}, y_{n})$, so just compute $k_{1}$ straight out using the value of $y_{n-1}$. Using that value, you can compute $k_{2} = f(t_{n} + h/2, y_{n} + k_{1}/2)$. Using that, you can compute $k_{3} = f(t_{n} + h, y_{n} - k_{1} + 2 k_{2} )$. Notice that you have $t_{0} = 0, y_{0} = 1$.

Comment: My confusion is what exactly is $f(t_n,y_n)$ in this case?

Comment: It's your function $f$ evaluated at $t_{n}, y_{n}$. Your $f(t, y) = -y^{2} \implies f(t_{n}, y_{n}) = -y_{n}^{2}$.

Comment: Thank you. My code was wrong, that was my problem.